# PHP echo date with one millisecond

Tags: php, date

How would I get only one millisecond added to date value so that it would be:

```
12:11:11.2
```

For the hours, minutes and seconds it is easy, but what to use to get just one (not three nor six)  millisecond value?

```
echo date('H:m:s.???');
```

Thanks

Comment: So what you want is the FIRST digit of the 3-digit millisecond part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substring the datetime return.
Date will always return 0 as it's input is integer.

```
echo substr((new \DateTime())->format('H:m:s.v'),0,-2);
```